# Python Convert matrix to List

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a python matrix as below

```
[
                [1603179035, "1"],
                [1603179095, "2"],
                [1603179155, "3"],
                [1603179215, "4"],
                [1603179275, "5"]
]
```

How can i convert it into 2 Lists as

```
list1 = [1603179035,1603179095,1603179155,1603179215,1603179275]
list2 = ["1","2","3","4',"5"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this one line of code (there is no needs to install external libraries...). Basically, all you have to do is to "unzip" your matrix:

```
lst = [
                [1603179035, "1"],
                [1603179095, "2"],
                [1603179155, "3"],
                [1603179215, "4"],
                [1603179275, "5"]
]

lst1, lst2 = map(list, zip(*lst))
```

Here is the output:

```
>>> lst1
[1603179035, 1603179095, 1603179155, 1603179215, 1603179275]
>>> lst2
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

```
lst = [
                [1603179035, "1"],
                [1603179095, "2"],
                [1603179155, "3"],
                [1603179215, "4"],
                [1603179275, "5"]
]

list1 = [element[0] for element in lst]
list2 = [element[1] for element in lst]

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[1603179035, 1603179095, 1603179155, 1603179215, 1603179275]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 2):

Easier if its a numpy array

```
import numpy as np

lst = [
                [1603179035, "1"],
                [1603179095, "2"],
                [1603179155, "3"],
                [1603179215, "4"],
                [1603179275, "5"]
]
lst = np.matrix(lst)
A, B = lst[:,0], lst[:,1]

# A = [1603179035, 1603179095, 1603179155, 1603179215, 1603179275]
# B = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Hope this helps, if you plan to use numpy matrices.
Matrices can be indexed in numpy mat[row_index, column_index].

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [
            [1603179035, "1"],
            [1603179095, "2"],
            [1603179155, "3"],
            [1603179215, "4"],
            [1603179275, "5"]
    ]
list1 = []
list2 = []
for elem in x:
    list1.append(elem[0])
    list2.append(elem[1])

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

here is another way to do it :)